# PDF Not Displaying Properly in Google Chrome When Hosted On My Server

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

This one has me scratching my head without any ideas of what else I can try. Whenever I try to stream a PDF that is hosted on my server in Google Chrome, I get the following blank screen with a little dot in the middle:

[image: What shows up when I try to display a PDF]

Here are some of my server details:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Web server: Apache 2

I even visited another random website with a PDF, https://cfsask.ca/images/pdfs/eBooks/ebook-Sales.pdf, which displays fine in Chrome, downloaded the pdf and then uploaded it to my server just to see if my server would be able to display ANY pdf files, but I have the same problem as before - Chrome just displays a blank screen with a dot in the middle.

Here are some more symptoms:

- In Chrome, I get the above dot shown above when hosting the PDF from my server.
- Firefox displays the PDF just fine from my server.
- Safari shows "blocked plugin" when hosting the PDF from my server.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem... it was with my Content Security Policy headers. I had included `object-src 'none';` in my CSP and it was prohibiting the pdf file from showing up.

I suspected it would be something with my headers based on the symptoms I outlined above, but it was difficult to debug because Google Chrome caches some of these headers and things didn't work until after I removed the `object-src 'none';`, restarted Apache on the server, part and then cleared the cache in Google Chrome.